# How to use count() when I use scrapy&xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using scrapy to deal with some parse work.

```
def parse_2(self,response):
   sel = Selector(response)
   sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="container"]')
   courses = []
   for site in sites:
       course = CourseItem()
       course['rating'] = site.xpath("count(//div[@class='span5'])")
       ……
```

I want to use the count function in xpath to count some nodes, but there is something wrong.
Like **exceptions.AttributeError:'Selector' object has no attribute 'decode'**
[image]

Comment: can you give some example input and desired output?

Comment: Your complete Spider code with appropriate URLs would also be useful. :)

Comment: I think you simply need to call `.extract()` on the `.xpath()` result: `course['rating'] = site.xpath("count(//div[@class='span5'])").extract()`. Also, I think your XPath expression in the loop should be relative: `course['rating'] = site.xpath("count(.//div[@class='span5'])").extract()` (i.e. counting `div` with class "span5" within each `div` of class "container")

Answer (score 7):

You can just use the counter python function len :

```
count = len(site.xpath("//div[@class='span5']"))
```

hope that help ;)
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
length = len(site.xpath("//div[@class='span5']").getall())
```